# SQL include count 0 if not there

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to do the following:

Select all products for this manufacturer in this country

For every product in this country  count the number of clicks for the time period specified.

If the count is 0 show 0.

So i satrted like this:

```
 -- yesterday data for scrollPartial/responsive (453)
select p.Description as Product, mw.Description as Widget,  COUNT(wc.Id)as WidgetClicks   from WidgetClicks wc
join ManufacturerWidgets mw on wc.ManufacturerWidgetId = mw.Id
join Products p on p.id = wc.ProductId
where wc.ManufacturerWidgetId = 453 and wc.CreatedAt > '2013-11-24 00:00:00.000' and wc.CreatedAt < '2013-11-25 00:00:00.000'
group by  p.Description, mw.Description
 order by Product
```

This gets me the amount  of clicks for each product - as long as the amount of clicks is not 0.

I have also tried seperating the days:

```
 select DatePart(week, wc.Createdat) as WeekNumber, DatePart(day, wc.Createdat) as dateOfMonth, datename(dw, wc.Createdat) as WeekDayName,p.Description as Product, mw.Description as Widget,  COUNT(wc.Id)as WidgetClicks   from WidgetClicks wc
join ManufacturerWidgets mw on wc.ManufacturerWidgetId = mw.Id
left join  Products p on p.id = wc.ProductId
where wc.ManufacturerWidgetId =453 and wc.CreatedAt > '2013-11-24 00:00:00.000' and wc.CreatedAt < '2013-11-25 00:00:00.000'
group by DatePart(week, wc.Createdat), DatePart(day, wc.Createdat), datename(dw, wc.Createdat), p.Description, mw.Description
 order by WeekNumber, dateOfMonth, WeekDayName, Product
```

and also select by product and doing a left join:

```
 select p.Description as Product, COUNT(wc.ProductId) as clicks from Products p
join productcountries pc on p.Id = pc.ProductId
 LEFT JOIN widgetclicks wc ON p.Id = wc.ProductId
where pc.CountryId = 231 and p.ManufacturerId = 129  and p.Discontinued = 0 and  wc.ManufacturerWidgetId =453 and wc.CreatedAt > '2013-11-20 00:00:00.000' and wc.CreatedAt < '2013-11-25 00:00:00.000' 
group by  p.Description
```

if i take off the following:

```
wc.ManufacturerWidgetId =453 and wc.CreatedAt > '2013-11-20 00:00:00.000' and wc.CreatedAt < '2013-11-25 00:00:00.000'
```

I can see 0 click counts so i think its must be because i have the widgetclick table in the where clause..?

So i want my table to look something like

```
Product Name    Widget Name    Click Count
Product1        Widget1         73
Product2        Widget1          0
Product3        Widget1          4
Product4        Widget1          2
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Think about the intermediate result sets that sql makes along the way before doing the GROUP BY statement. If there are no records for Product 2/Widget 1 in the WidgetClicks table, you can't use an Inner Join, because then your result set doesn't have any Widget 1 records.

The LEFT JOIN was a good step, but then you knocked out the Product 2/Widget 1 rows with this bit:

```
wc.CreatedAt > '2013-11-20 00:00:00.000' and wc.CreatedAt < '2013-11-25 00:00:00.000'
```

The rows for Product 2/Widget 1 in your set have NULLs in the wc.CreatedAt field. The LEFT JOIN worked correctly and made an intermediate set with Product 2/Widget 1, but then the WHERE clause filtered them out.

The solution is to move these conditions up into the join. The condition filters out which widgetclicks records are considered, but since the condition is no longer in the WHERE, it doesn't apply to the result set containing the products bit.

```
select p.Description as Product, COUNT(wc.ProductId) as clicks 
from Products p
  join productcountries pc on p.Id = pc.ProductId
  LEFT JOIN widgetclicks wc 
    ON p.Id = wc.ProductId
      and  wc.ManufacturerWidgetId =453 
      and wc.CreatedAt > '2013-11-20 00:00:00.000' 
      and wc.CreatedAt < '2013-11-25 00:00:00.000'
where pc.CountryId = 231 and p.ManufacturerId = 129  and p.Discontinued = 0   
group by  p.Description
```

Comment: i never considered moving the conditions into the join thank you for highlighting that and the nice explanation!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this
sorry code not tested and maybe not work
it's only for eexample

```
select p.*, wc.cnt
  from Product p
  left join (select wc.ProductId, count(*) as cnt
               from WidgetClicks wc
              where wc.ManufacturerWidgetId = 453
                and wc.CreatedAt > '2013-11-24 00:00:00.000'
                and wc.CreatedAt < '2013-11-25 00:00:00.000') wc
    on (p.productid = wc.productid)
```